Running Electron App Doesn't Close After Uninstalling
I have developed an Electron.js application and successfully launched it. While the application is running in the background, I proceeded to uninstall it from my system. However, I've noticed that even after completing the uninstallation process, the application continues to run in the background. It doesn't automatically close or terminate, despite being uninstalled.
Is there a way to ensure that the running instance of the application closes automatically when the application is uninstalled?

Fixed this issue , i have added include property in nsis config (package.json) and created installation.nsh where i added code for close the application and clear the data , [ but this is only supported for nsis not for msi ]
find here
